# Preventing WCF in IIS7 from caching authentication certificates

Tags: wcf, iis-7, x509certificate

I'm building a WCF-based application with the users authenticating using certificates on smart cards. The service is hosted on IIS7 and the clients are Windows forms apps.

The problem is that when a new user is added (new certificate created) that user can't log in until the IIS is restarted or the application pool recycled. If an existing user is deleted he's also able to log on until a restart/recycle.

In my behaviour definition I have

```
        <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="blahblah.local" 
    x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
     membershipProviderName="SqlMembershipProvider" cacheLogonTokens="true"/>
            <clientCertificate>
                <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" 
certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="Online"/>
            </clientCertificate>
        </serviceCredentials>
```

Is there any way to prevent this certificate "caching" from taking place or refresh the active certificate list on demand?

Comment: How do you add new certificates / clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the caching was a known "feature" of System.Identitymodel. It's discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/23455b64-6e69-461b-8a5b-08a17467d260) and more info available [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457027.aspx#EKAA).

What I did was to use a custom validator (code below) which took care of the issue.

**EDIT**: Added more code for validating X.509 certificates against CRL's in real-time [here](http://blog.ginzburgconsulting.com/real-time-crl-validation-for-x-509-certificates-in-net/)

web.config

```
<clientCertificate>
    <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="My.IdentityModel.MyX509Validator, My.IdentityModel" />
</clientCertificate>
```

code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace My.IdentityModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom X.509 certificate validator
    /// Richard Ginzburg - richard (at) ginzburgconsulting (dot) com
    /// </summary>
    public class MyX509Validator : X509CertificateValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            if (certificate == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate", "Certificate validation failed, no certificate provided");
            }

            X509ChainPolicy myChainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy
                                                {
                                                    RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online,
                                                    RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain,
                                                    VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag,
                                                    UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10),
                                                    VerificationTime = DateTime.Now
                                                };
            X509Chain chain = new X509Chain(true) {ChainPolicy = myChainPolicy};

            try
            {
                bool ok = chain.Build(certificate);
                if(!ok)
                {
                    foreach (var status in chain.ChainStatus)
                    {
                        Logging.Log("MyX509Validator: Validation failed - " + status.StatusInformation);
                    }
                    throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Certificate validation failed when building chain");
                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Certificate validation failed when building chain, " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```